# Work done by a force field line integrals

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Find the work done by the force field $F(x, y) = \langle 2x \sin(y), 2y \rangle$ on a particle that moves along the parabola $y = x^2$ from $(-1, 1)$ to $(2, 4)$.

So to use line integrals to solve this I took $r(x) = \langle x, x^2 \rangle$. Then  $$\int_{-1}^2 \langle 2x \sin{x^2}, 2x^2 \rangle \cdot \langle 1, 2x \rangle = \int_{-1}^2 2x \sin{x^2} + 4x^2 dx.$$ Does that work?

Comment: That looks fine, except the integrand should have $4x^3$, and not $4x^2$ I believe.

Comment: @msteve oh yeah, thanks!

Comment: @msteve You should make that an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The integral should be the following:
\begin{align}
\int_{-1}^2 F(x,x^2) \cdot r(x) dx 
&= \int_{-1}^2 \langle 2x\sin(x^2), 2x^2 \rangle \cdot \langle 1, 2x \rangle dx \\
&= \int_{-1}^2 (2x\sin(x^2) + 4x^3) dx \\
&= -\cos(x^2) + x^4 \bigg|_{-1}^2 \\
&= 15 + \cos(1) - \cos(4).
\end{align}